# EntityFramework storing sensitive data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Say on one of your entities you have a property that when you need saved to the database, it needs to be encrypted but when you're dealing with it in code, you just want to treat is as plain text.

Right now, I have this setup:

```
public class MyEntity 
{
   [SecureStringAttribute]
   public string SecureString {get;set;}
}
```

My DbContext, this is where the "magic" happens.

```
public MyDbContext()
    : base("conn")
{
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.SavingChanges += ObjectContextOnSavingChanges;
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += ObjectContextOnObjectMaterialized;
}

private void ObjectContextOnObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
{
    DecryptSecureString(e.Entity);
}

private void ObjectContextOnSavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EncryptSecureStrings(sender as ObjectContext);
}

private void DecryptSecureString(object entity)
{
    if (entity != null)
    {
        foreach (
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo in
                EntityFrameworkSecureStringAttribute.GetSecureStringProperties(entity.GetType()))
        {
            string encryptedValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(entity) as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedValue))
            {
                string decryptedValue = EncDec.Decrypt(encryptedValue);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(entity, decryptedValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void EncryptSecureStrings(ObjectContext context)
{

    if (context != null)
    {
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry objectStateEntry in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified).Where(x => x.Entity != null))
        {

            object[] data = new object[objectStateEntry.CurrentValues.FieldCount];
            objectStateEntry.CurrentValues.GetValues(data);

            PropertyInfo[] properties =
                EntityFrameworkSecureStringAttribute.GetSecureStringProperties(objectStateEntry.Entity.GetType());

            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                string currentValue = objectStateEntry.CurrentValues[propertyInfo.Name] as string;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue))
                {
                    int index = objectStateEntry.CurrentValues.GetOrdinal(propertyInfo.Name);
                    string newVal = EncDec.Encrypt(currentValue);
                    objectStateEntry.CurrentValues.SetValue(index, newVal);

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It's straight forward I just encrypt/decrypt the string on save and on load. However if I do the following:

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity(){SecureString= "This is secret!!"};
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

At this point `entity.SecureString` has been encrypted and any further use with this object will be incorrect.

Comment: Have you considered leaving `SecureString` alone and marking it as `protected` and then exposing a `DecryptedString` property that uses `SecureString` as its backing store centralizing the encrypt/decrypt logic in the get/set of that property? The attribute/reflection solution seems a bit over-baked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both of your suggestions, i have decided to go along with this.... I always seemed to figures stuff out after posting on SO.

I wanted to go for an approach where i don't have to have to worry about adding NotMapped properties etc, although i know this works fine.

Just override the SaveChanges method like this.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    int result = base.SaveChanges();

    foreach (DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        DecryptSecureString(dbEntityEntry.Entity);
    }
    return result;
}
```

All this does is after the SaveChanges is called,we go back through and decyryped anyting we need to.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't touch the `SaveChanges` code. Try playing with `SavedChanges` event of the context in a symmetrical way to what you do in `SavingChanges`. This event occurs after your data was saved to the database.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of one single property that will be flipped to/from being encrypted, you can do it with a pair of properties - one that is always encrypted, and one that is never encrypted.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string EncryptedInfo { get; set; }
    public string PlainTextInfo { 
        get
        {
            return Decrypt(EncryptedInfo);
        }
        set
        {
            EncryptedInfo = Encrypt(value);
        }
}
```

And in the model builder, ignore the unencrypted property:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
            .Ignore(m => m.PlainTextInfo);
    }
}
```

As long as you don't mess with the encrypted property elsewhere in your application, it should work well.

Answer (score 2):

Add a property `UnsecuredString` and decorate it with `[NotMapped]` attribute.
Implement the getter and setter to decrypt and encrypt the SecureString data.